# JS: access variable from AJAX success

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have this piece of JS:

```
  $.ajax({
    url: '/my-url',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(json) {
      for (var i = 0, ien = json.data.length; i < ien; i++) {
        createPanel(json.data[i]);
        var options = json.options;
        console.log(options);
      }
    }
  });
```

which gets me JSON like this:

```
{
    "data": [{
        "id": "2",
        "item": {
            "name": "something here...",
            "company": "1"
        },
        "companies": {
            "name": "my super company"
        }
    }],
    "options": {
        "company": [{
            "value": 2,
            "label": "my second name"
        }, {
            "value": 1,
            "label": "my super company"
        }]
    }
}
```

In console log I can see my `json.options` which then I need to populate in this piece of code later in same JS file:

```
  editor.field('company').update(
    // options.company "value", "label" has to be populated here
  );
```

How do I access my `options` variable later in my code, please? Thank you!

**The solution**

Looks like adjusting my code to something like this, does the trick:

```
  $.ajax({
      url: '/my-url',
      dataType: 'json'
    })
    .done(callback)
    .done(function(json) {
      for (var i = 0, ien = json.data.length; i < ien; i++) {
        createPanel(json.data[i]);
      }
    });

  function callback(response) {
    var options = response.options.company;
    editor.field('company').update(options);
  }
```

Comment: loop through `json.options.company`

Answer (score -1):

You simply need to loop through and get the `label` and `value`:

```js
var json = {
    "data": [{
        "id": "2",
        "item": {
            "name": "something here...",
            "company": "1"
        },
        "companies": {
            "name": "my super company"
        }
    }],
    "options": {
        "company": [{
            "value": 2,
            "label": "my second name"
        }, {
            "value": 1,
            "label": "my super company"
        }]
    }
};

$(json.options.company).each(function(k, v){
  console.log('Label: ' + v.label + ' And value is ' + v.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why even use jQuery for simply enumerating an array?

Comment: Because OP has tagged JQuery and is using JQuery. Check the code in question.

Comment: Presumably that's for the Ajax call, you don't need jQuery to enumerate an array

Comment: Well, he is receiving JSON and he needs values from it which he will be populating somewhere. I wonder, whats wrong here and why the downvote?

Comment: @Jamiec The piece of code is taken from bigger JQuery code, so I tagged it. It can probably be vanilla JS as well.

Comment: Because you're using a clubhammer to crack a nut!

Comment: Alright, so you can provide OP an alternative solution.

Comment: @Jamiec I added my solution above. As I'm still learning, could you take a look, please? It's working, however I'd like to know I do it up to some general rules and standards.

Comment: @matiss yes, that's the right sort of idea. It is asynchronous so you must do things similar to how youve done it. Well done for reading the linked duplicate and trying to understand yourself.

Comment: @Jamiec Thank you for pointing to right direction. I wasn't sure about looping thing as basically my `options` were in JSON already - I just needed to grab them. Thanks again!